# How to exclude an optional trailing comma from string capture?

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm banging my head against a wall trying to allow for an optional trailing comma to be excluded (not captured).  I'm trying to extract the name from an email salutation (generated from a template) and need the regex to not capture the trailing comma; but I'm also trying to build in some allowance in case someone accidentally deletes the trailing comma.  I've placed the comma in a non-capturing group and made it optional (zero r one of), but it still gets included in the output.

regex expression: `(?:Hi|Dear)\s*(.*)(?:,?)`

input: `Hi John,`

expected output: `John`

actual output: `John,`

I'm not sure if the issue is related to something like regex not liking more than one non-capturing group in the same expression, but if I set the comma as non-optional it behaves as expected:

regex expression: `(?:Hi|Dear)\s*(.*),`

input: `Hi John,`

expected output: `John`

actual output: `John`

---

Any help would much appreciated

For reference https://regex101.com/r/WzbxD9/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.*` in your expression is greedy, so it's already including the comma.  Instead you could match anything *but* comma, followed by an optional comma:

```
(?:Hi|Dear)\s*([^,]+),?
```

Extra credit:  What about a salutation that mentions multiple people, like "Dear John, David, and Abby,"

That's a little trickier, but you could allow any characters in the name so long as it ends with one non-comma, followed by an optional comma:

```
(?:Hi|Dear)\s*(.+[^,\s]),?
```

Here, group 1 captures "John, David, and Abby" without the trailing comma.

Comment: Hi Iguanaut, thanks for coming back so quickly too!  If the input is missing the comma your first suggestion captures everything after (and including) the salutation, including new-line characters and the body of the email too.  I played around with it and got the desired result by adding a /n to the end of your first expression `(?:Hi|Dear)\s*([^,]+),?\n`.

Your second suggestion behaves perfectly as required straight off the bat, thank you so much! I didn't even think about matching anything but the comma and then the optional comma, great idea!

Answer (score 1):

Just make the last character "not a comma":

```
(?:Hi|Dear)\s*(.*[^,])
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/4CNxFbRo73B4en).

This works for a variety of input formats:

| Input | Match group 1 |
| --- | --- |
| `Hi John` | `John` |
| `Hi John,` | `John` |
| `Dear John, Sally and Fred` | `Dear John, Sally and Fred` |
| `Dear John, Sally and Fred,` | `Dear John, Sally and Fred` |

Comment: Hi Bohemian, thanks for the quick reply!  Sorry, I may have worded my question poorly above.   The trailing comma is always unwanted in the output, but I need the option for the salutation to be extracted whether a comma is present or not (in case it is accidentally deleted out of the email template).  Your suggestion above still includes the comma in the output, as part of the capturing group, but thanks for the suggestion and quick assistance!

Comment: @Nackers *No*, my regex *does not* include the comma. Please see linked demo